# php display info in form

Tags: php, html

I have a function allowing members to update their personal details when they have logged in, the update page features a form the user will fill in and when the submit button is pressed the deatils are updated. This works fine, I am wanting to display the users current details in the appropriate text filed in the form e.g. the firstname text field will have value "James" and the user can delete this to enter "jim". Is it something to do with adding a value to the form field? My form is shown below.

```
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Firstname</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="78">Surname</td>
    <td width="6">:</td>
    <td width="294"><input name="surname" type="text" id="surname"></td>
    </tr>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Three table cells to do what a label/input can do. Awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print value inside the text box.

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $someValue; ?>" />`

Comment: @josh i din see your answer before i post.. :(

Comment: Thans will i have to declare the variable $firstname like this?    $firstname= $row["firstname"];

Comment: @user1368371 plz accept answer if its useful. Yes you can get value to a variable or you can print it directly inside the value with echo.

Answer (score 1):

`echo '<input type="text" value="'. $someValue .'" />';`

OR

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $someValue; ?>" />`

Both obviously require that you be in a .php file, and that `$someValue` contains the appropriate value to set. Watch out for the double quotes around the value, too. Without them, any spaces will break the value when it's rendered.

Comment: Your answer is great, could you please add `<?= $someValue ?>` as third option. I found it perfectly suitable for cases like this one

Comment: @Kyborek: I didn't include that example, because short tags are now deprecated: http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2009/06/maximum-failure-php-6-deprecates-short.html

Comment: Oh i missed that one, you got a point and thanks for the info.

Comment: @Josh As of 5.4, `<?=` always works regardless of the short tags directive.